# Positive integer solutions to $ p+q^{n}=x^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Consider two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
p+q^2=r^2,
$$
and $r\in\mathbb N$. It is not difficult to figure out that for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and  $x\in\mathbb N$ there are no solutions of
$$
p^{2}+q^{n}=x^2.
$$
What about
$$
p+q^{n}=x^2,
$$
with $n>2$? So far I was only able to prove that there are no positive integer solutions if $q=2$. The question is a variation of a problem in the Italian 2019 mathematical Olympiads.

Comment: It [depends](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005598/for-every-odd-prime-number-p-there-exists-a-unique-natural-number-x-such-tha/2005607#2005607)...

Comment: Isn't $p=17, q=2, n=3, x=5$ a solution with $n>2, q=2$?

Comment: 17+4=21 is not a square

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p + q^2 = r^2$ means $p = r^2 - q^2 = (r+q)(r-q)$.  Since $p$ is prime, this implies $r-q=1$ and $r+q=p$, i.e. $p=2q+1$.

If $n > 2$ is even,
$p + q^n = r^2$ means $p = (r+q^{n/2})(r-q^{n/2})$, 
so $r=q^{n/2}+1$ and $p = r + q^{n/2} = 2 q^{n/2}+1$.

If $n$ is divisible by $4$, there can't be solutions with $q \ne 3$, as 
$2 q^{n/2}+1$ would be divisible by $3$.  For $n$ even but not divisible by $4$,
I would expect solutions to exist.

Some examples:

$$\eqalign{5 + 2^2 &= 3^2\cr
19 + 3^4 &= 10^2\cr
17 + 2^6 &= 9^2\cr
163 + 3^8 &= 82^2\cr
487 + 3^{10} &= 244^2\cr
1459 + 3^{12} &= 730^2\cr
257 + 2^{14} &= 129^2\cr
39367 + 3^{18} &= 19684^2\cr
5264950288664609755476607823 + 311^{22} &= 2632475144332304877738303912^2\cr
2441406251 + 5^{26} &= 1220703126^2\cr
65537 + 2^{30} &= 32769^2\cr
}$$

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your last request of

$$p + q^n = x^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

having any solutions for $n \gt 2$, and not including $q = 2$. An example is $p = 19$, $q = 3$, $n = 4$ and $x = 10$ since $19 + 3^4 = 19 + 81 = 100 = 10^2$.